# How to disable ssh when running vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

I'm booting up a empty box, c33s/empty, to make it do a PXE boot and install coreos on the machine. Everything works as it should, but as vagrant by default do some ssh communication for provisioning and other stuff it hangs due to that the ssh-key is installed in the PXE boot process. This prevents me from starting several nodes at the same time. At the moment I need to press ctrl-c then when message `node1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...` is shown and then rerun `vagrant up` to get then next node to start.

I have not found any way to disable the ssh step when running vagrant up. I have tried --no-provision, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you put *config.ssh.insert_key: false* into the Vagrantfile, this step should be avoided. Is this practical in your environment? Ref: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html#config-ssh-insert_key

Comment: This may have worked in previous versions or with certain providers but it doesn't seem to help today. Interesting you can't set config.vm.communicator=NULL either.